# How to update React npm package in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: npm, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, react-redux, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a dotnet core 2.0 app using the React+ Redux template in VS2017. The template comes with react v15.6.1 by default, and I would like to upgrade this to v16.

I first tried going into the npm packages  folder under the project dependencies list, and right clicking on react > Update Package. The update said it was completed but this however did not actually change my react version.

I then went into the package.json file and started typing in the new version and 16.2.0 came up as an intellisense option, but when I saved the file the package again did not update.

Has anyone figured out how to update the React version that comes with the template, there are a number of improvements in v16 I would like to make use of.

Answer (score 4):

Here we go

After opening VS2017 go to

> 1) Tools -> NuGet Package Manager  -> Package Manager Console

You will see Package Manager Console at the bottom pointing as PM>

> 2) Go to your root directory of main projects package.json file.

eg.

```
PM> cd D:\Myproject
```

3) Once you are in main directory type command below.

```
PM> ncu -u
```

After hitting this command, you will get notifications as below.

Using `D:\Myproject\package.json`

```
 @types/history                      4.6.0  â†’    4.6.2 
 @types/react                      15.0.35  â†’   16.3.8 
 @types/react-dom                   15.5.1  â†’   16.0.5 
 @types/react-hot-loader             3.0.3  â†’    3.0.6 
 @types/react-redux                 4.4.45  â†’   5.0.16 
 @types/react-router                4.0.12  â†’   4.0.23 
 @types/react-router-dom             4.0.5  â†’    4.2.6 
 @types/react-router-redux           5.0.3  â†’   5.0.13 
 @types/webpack                     2.2.15  â†’    4.1.3 
 @types/webpack-env                 1.13.0  â†’   1.13.5 
 awesome-typescript-loader           3.2.1  â†’    5.0.0 
 bootstrap                           3.3.7  â†’    4.1.0 
 css-loader                         0.28.4  â†’  0.28.11 
 event-source-polyfill               0.0.9  â†’   0.0.12 
 extract-text-webpack-plugin         2.1.2  â†’    3.0.2 
 file-loader                        0.11.2  â†’   1.1.11 
 history                             4.6.3  â†’    4.7.2 
 jquery                              3.2.1  â†’    3.3.1 
 react                              15.6.1  â†’   16.3.1 
 react-dom                          15.6.1  â†’   16.3.1 
 react-hot-loader             3.0.0-beta.7  â†’    4.0.1 
 react-redux                         5.0.5  â†’    5.0.7 
 react-router-dom                    4.1.1  â†’    4.2.2 
 redux                               3.7.1  â†’    3.7.2 
 style-loader                       0.18.2  â†’   0.20.3 
 typescript                          2.4.1  â†’    2.8.1 
 url-loader                          0.5.9  â†’    1.0.1 
 webpack                             2.5.1  â†’    4.5.0 
 webpack-hot-middleware             2.18.2  â†’   2.22.0 
 webpack-merge                       4.1.0  â†’    4.1.2 
 aspnet-webpack  ^2.0.1  â†’  ^2.0.3
```

Upgraded `D:\Myproject\package.json`

If you still getting older versions

Then hit this commands

> 1. npm install -g npm-check-updates
> 2. ncu -u

[Ref](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-4-app-angular-5-visual-studio-2017/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit package.json and change the version of react, save THEN trigger the update.

Comment: This allowed me to update to 16.2.2 by right clicking and updating, but does not seem to fix the issue, as every time I do I package restore(by right clicking on npm> restore packages, or when triggered by changing another package in packages.json), the React package reverts to 15.6.1

Comment: Did you run `npm install`? Without that, your package lock will not update and it will keep reverting.